# I deleted the known_hosts file from .ssh folder and I can't pull or push in BitBucket repositories

Tags: git, ssh, key, bitbucket

I made a mistake and deleted the "known_hosts" file in ".ssh" folder! Now I can't pull or push in BitBucket repositories.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try executing:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

It would give you a message somethign like:

```
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (207.223.240.181)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Say `yes` after verifying the host fingerprint (see details in the end).

Then you should get this warning, which you can ignore safely:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,207.223.240.181' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
conq: logged in as tuxdude.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Try running the `git pull` or `git push` once again and it should work this time.

NOTE: I assume you still have your `.ssh/id_rsa` file safely which is your private key for SSH authentication.

## Verifying Host Fingerprint

As @Pascal_dher pointed out, you can be a victim of man-in-the-middle attack if you do not verify the host's fingerprint (using some out of band approach that you can rely on). For bitbucket, the info is [available here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucketCloud-KnownhostorBitbucket'spublickeyfingerprints).

Comment: You need to check the fingerprint - otherwise you can be man-in-the-middled. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucketCloud-KnownhostorBitbucket'spublickeyfingerprints

Comment: Thanks @Pascal_dher - Good point. So I've added the info to the post.

Answer (score 3):

From the ["using ssh with BitBucket" page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket), the next use of ssh should re-create that `known_hosts` file:

> Bitbucket hosts only allow Git and Mercurial to make SSH connections.
>   The first time you access Bitbucket using the SSH URL, your SSH client checks to see if the Bitbucket host is a known host. If the host is not in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file SSH warns you that it is adding the Bitbucket host to known hosts:

```
$ hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/newuserme/mquotefork testkey
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (207.223.240.182)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

> If you view the contents of known hosts is stored you find the actual key is stored in a base64 encoded format:

```
bitbucket.org,207.223.240.182 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAubiN81eDcafrgMeLzaFPsw2kNvEcqTKl/VqLat/MaB33pZy0y3rJZtnqwR2qOOvbwKZYKiEO1O6VqNEBxKvJJelCq0dTXWT5pbO2gDXC6h6QDXCaHo6pOHGPUy+YBaGQRGuSusMEASYiWunYN0vCAI8QaXnWMXNMdFP3jHAJH0eDsoiGnLPBlBp4TNm6rYI74nMzgz3B9IikW4WVK+dc8KZJZWYjAuORU3jc1c/NPskD2ASinf8v3xnfXeukU0sJ5N6m5E8VLjObPEO+mN2t/FZTMZLiFqPWc/ALSqnMnnhwrNi2rbfg/rd/IpL8Le3pSBne8+seeFVBoGqzHM9yXw==
```

So simply using an ssh address (or just ssh command) should be enough to trigger that message again.