# [ubuntu 13.04] why my git use different key files?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I want to clone some source code to my server via git, so:

```
root@wemet:~# ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
79:ff:5d:07:9f:64:a7:d2:3f:81:0c:4d:ac:54:4e:fe root@wemet
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
| oo |
| .+o |
| . +o |
| . o .. |
| S . o oE.|
| . . +o=o|
| o o.=|
| o +o|
| . +|
+-----------------+
root@wemet:~# git clone ssh://git@git.cloudbees.com/foretribe/wetest.git
Cloning into 'wetest'...
The authenticity of host 'git.cloudbees.com (54.235.125.211)' can't be establis
ed.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 39:fe:eb:80:cd:56:bb:42:0e:bc:77:85:2c:9b:14:d2.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
root@wemet:~#
```

you can see the ssh-keygen generate the file with fingerprint 79:ff:5d:07:9f:64:a7:d2:3f:81:0c:4d:ac:54:4e:fe
but when I want to apply to the git command the file fingerprint is:
39:fe:eb:80:cd:56:bb:42:0e:bc:77:85:2c:9b:14:d2

the git command should retrieve the default ssh key files
it should store at /root/.ssh/
why the ssh get other file? where it is?

That means they are totally different files!!!

Comment: `ssh-keygen` generates your key. The fingerprint shows the host key.

Comment: The fingerprint of `git.cloudbees.com`'s host key is completely different from the fingerprint of your locally generated user id key. What were you expecting?

Comment: @Charles Bailey，I added my locally generated id_rsa.pub to cloudbees, but the problem is on my local git it use different files.

Comment: What makes you think that your local git is using a different private key file?

Comment: @Charles Bailey 1,permission denity if I put yes, 2, the  fingerprint different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no

You are supposed to answer 'yes' (which will add that host to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file).
This has nothing to do with your ssh public key.

**This is not** your "git using a different file".

This is your ssh session asking you to confirm you know about this remote host.
Then ssh will use your public key.

A simple [ssh -T git@git.cloudbees.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535861/6309) would trigger the same message (at least until you accept that host).
(Or [you can use `ssh-keyscan`](https://serverfault.com/a/366751/783))

Comment: I added my locally generated id_rsa.pub to cloudbees, it was: 79:ff:5d:07:9f:64:a7:d2:3f:81:0c:4d:ac:54:4e:febut the problem is on my local git it use different files.

Comment: my git is not apply the file my generated id_rsa.pub

Comment: @user504909 the "`ECDSA key fingerprint is 39:fe:eb:80:cd:56:bb:42:0e:bc:77:85:2c:9b:14:d2`" has *nothing* to do with your key. This is NOT your "git using a different key".

Comment: if I put yes, I still can not downloaded it as permission denity say I do not have right to do something....

Comment: @user504909 did you put your public key on the cloudbee server? (http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/How+to+set+your+Public+Key+for+Git+Access)